# Don't wait for function to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Spawn a thread”-like behaviour in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042648/spawn-a-thread-like-behaviour-in-node-js)

How can I make my code continue without waiting for extensive operations to complete?

```
var foo = function()
{
    var i = 1000000000;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i--;
    }
};
console.log("start");
foo();
console.log("end");
```

**EDIT**
This is not for web development. I'm using node.js

Comment: async.js is a flow control library, like chovy mentioned. while node.js also supports lower level actions, such as starting a separate web_worker or child process like elclanrs has mentioned. either of these two would help you in this case.

Comment: I was actually gonna provide a better link but I guess this works fine https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: I have seen in cases of node.js webservers where a function is executed and immediately returns, though I don't fully understand how (and it's done without async.js). Also, @pilotcam The post you suggested is similar, though I don't see how the answer suggested could be applied here (feel free to prove me wrong of course :D ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `node.js`, you can use `process.nextTick()` for this. It will defer executing the long running task until the next pass around the event loop.

```
var foo = function()
{
    var i = 1000000000;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i--;
    }
};
console.log("start");
process.nextTick(foo());
console.log("end");
```

Keep in mind while this will allow this request to return immediately, it will still block the thread when it eventually gets executed.  Node.js isn't meant for long running CPU intensive tasks, it's optimized for handling lots and lots of lightweight connections.

If you need to do CPU intensive stuff with node, you should look at a job queue (like `kue` or any other pub/sub implementation) where you place jobs on a queue where a second node.js process can listen for new jobs and execute them as they come in.

This will allow your main node processes to handle new requests quickly and allow a couple of background node processes to handle all of these long running jobs.